# Applying is.logical to a list with multiple data types

Tags: r, typechecking

I'm trying to figure out how to do some data quality checking on a code.

Suppose I have

```
x <- list(1,2,T)
y <- list(1,2,3)
```

I want to be able to apply a function which will flag 'x' as having bad data.

```
if(any(is.logical(x))) stop('Bad data')
```

but

```
if(any(is.logical(y)))
```

won't trigger an error.

I know I could do it with a for loop, but I'm hoping to find a simpler solution.

**For Loop Solution**

```
for (tmp in x) {if (is.logical(tmp)) stop('Bad data')}
```

Comment: this is an application of using `sapply` to vectorise functions, try: `any(sapply(x, is.logical))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution is to use sapply.

```
> any(sapply(x,is.logical))
[1] TRUE

> any(sapply(y,is.logical))
[1] FALSE
```

Note that using any and sapply is significantly slower than using a for loop.

```
> system.time(any(sapply(x,is.logical)))
  user  system elapsed 
  1.58    0.02    1.61 

> system.time(for (blah in x) {if(is.logical(x)) {}})
  user  system elapsed 
  0.29    0.00    0.29
```

Using vapply as suggested below

```
> system.time(any(vapply(x, is.logical, logical(1))))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.30    0.01    0.28
```

Comment: `sapply` is slower because of running `simplify2array`. Instead, `any(vapply(x, is.logical, logical(1L)))` will perform as "well" as the `for` loop.